# How to send an HTTP request to an application started within the same Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins

I have a simple REST application that I want to test using Jenkins. The Jenkins build compiles the binary, runs it in a shell with parameters and then sends an HTTP POST to the application using a Jenkins plugin.

The problem is that the HTTP request build step doesn't run until the Execute shell has terminated, so it always receives a 408 error.

How can I have the shell script stay running for long enough that I can send it some HTTP requests? Someone suggested Jenkins Pipelines but that seems more heavy-duty than should be needed here.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, you need to let your application running while the build process continue to run.

To achieve what you want, you'll have to do start your application in background during the shell call (probably with a `&` at the end of the command under linux OS or using a tool like [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/))... **BUT** Jenkins will not allow you to do such thing...well, if you don't know how to whisper to it ;)

To allow jenkins to let you leak descriptors and process during build, you'll have to use a trick, that is to set the `BUILD_ID` to something else than the current BUILD_ID.

Something like `set BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` before starting your daemonized application should be explicit enough

That way, you'll be able to start your application in a build step, and then, in another step occurring after, you'll be able to send to it your HTTP request.

Do not forget to stop the application before the build is finished to avoid to let this process stay and occupy memory for nothing.

[You can find more details on the Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build)

Answer (score 0):

If the application runs on Linux you can start it in background with 'screen'.